# Does Git take time into account to avoid branch "races"? or does merge order matter?

Tags: git

Suppose at noon on branch A you create a file:

```
A
```

at 1 you create a branch B from A, and change the file to:

```
A
B    
C
```

at 2, someone else creates C off A, and changes the file to:

```
A
B
C
D
```

at 3, they merge C into A, so A is now:

```
A
B
C
D
```

at 4 someone creates a branch D off A, and changes the file to:

```
A
```

at 5, the original person to create a branch merges B into A, meaning that on A the file is:

```
A
B
C
```

finally, at 6, branch D gets merged into A, leaving, as the final result(?):

```
A
```

My question is does Git know how to see this as a merge conflict?  Does it look at time?  Or just 3-way diff with a common ancestor, and if it "goes" lexically it goes?

In this example, branch D is clobbering B, even though it was created from A *after* B committed (in B, but before merging back into A).  If that is the case, you would get a different outcome if the last two commits were not B->A then D->A, but the other way around(D->A first, then B->A).

Comment: Pleased provide an ASCII diagram for the graph.

Comment: The lengthy answer below both provides the picture and all other needed pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Git, [time is not important.  Only  <strike>life</strike>  the graph is important.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrB9ciZTxyo)  (Of course, the graph itself is built over time, so one can argue that time does matter in a way, but read on.)

> Suppose at noon on branch A you create a file [containing one line reading `A`]

Branches don't really matter either, not in the sense that you might think.  Whether branches matter depends on what you mean by *branch* (see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)).  Remember, every commit, identified by its unique hash ID, has:

- a complete snapshot of all of the source files;
- the author name, email, and time-stamp;
- the committer name, email, and time-stamp;
- **the hash ID of the *parent* commit(s)**; and
- the log message.

It's the bolded item above—the hash ID of the commit's parent—that matters here, as this forms the graph.  The two time-stamps, author and committer, are essentially arbitrary: you can override one or both at the time you make the commit.  (Once the commit is made, they are part of the commit's data, and cannot be changed.  No part of any commit can ever be changed: at most, you can make a *copy* of that commit, with some item(s) changed, and get a *new* commit, with a new and different unique hash ID, and convince everyone to start using the new commit in place of the old one.)

Let's give each commit a unique `C<number>` ID (I usually use uppercase letters but you have called the branches `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` here, so let's go with `C1` through `C7` for the commits).

Meanwhile, a branch *name*—see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452) again—is just a pointer to one specific commit, with the peculiar property that when we `git checkout` that branch and make a *new* commit, Git updates the name to point to the new commit we just made.  Meanwhile, the new commit we just made stores, as its parent, the hash ID of the previous commit.  So, let's say we have a branch named `A`, pointing to some existing commit `C1`, which has some parent we're not going to draw in:

```
...  <-C1   <-- A
```

The branch name `A` contains the hash ID for `C1`.  You `git checkout A` so that `C1` becomes the current commit with `A` becoming the current branch:

```
...--C1   <-- A (HEAD)
```

(drawing the connectors from commits to their parents as arrows is about to become a problem, so I'm switching to `--` instead here).  You then make a new file, `git add` it, and make a new commit `C2`.  This makes the name `A` identify commit `C2`, whose parent is `C1`:

```
...--C1--C2   <-- A (HEAD)
```

> at 1, you create a branch B from A ...

(via, for instance: `git checkout -b B A`.)

Now you have:

```
...--C1--C2   <-- A, B (HEAD)
```

> ... and change the file to [have three lines reading `A` `B` and `C`]

Assuming you run `git add` and `git commit`, you now have a new commit, and `B` identifies it; the new commit's parent is `C2`:

```
...--C1--C2   <-- A
           \
            C3   <-- B (HEAD)
```

> at 2, someone else creates C off A ...

(e.g., `git checkout -b C A`).  So let's draw that:

```
...--C1--C2   <-- A, C (HEAD)
           \
            C3   <-- B
```

> and changes the file to [four lines, `A` `B` `C` and `D`, in that order]

Assuming the usual add-and-commit, we get commit `C4`, to which `C` now points:

```
            C4   <-- C (HEAD)
           /
...--C1--C2   <-- A
           \
            C3   <-- B
```

> at 3, they merge C into A

At this point, it becomes important to find out precisely *which* command(s) they use to do this, because commit `C4` is strictly ahead of commit `C2`.  This means that:

```
git checkout A
git merge C
```

will do a *fast-forward* merge, resulting in:

```
            C4   <-- A (HEAD), C
           /
...--C1--C2
           \
            C3   <-- B
```

If they use `git merge --no-ff C`, however, Git will perform a true merge (which is nonetheless trivial), resulting in:

```
            C4   <-- C
           /  \
...--C1--C2----C5   <-- A (HEAD)
           \
            C3   <-- B
```

where the contents of the file that was new in `C2`, as stored in in commit `C5`, match the contents of the same-named file in `C4`.  A trivial merge just takes the "graph-wise-later" commit's content, through an obvious simplification of the general rule we'll see in a moment.

Either way, the name `A` points to a commit in which the file has the three line form, but one way, `A` points to a *different* commit than does `C`.

> at 4, someone creates a branch D off A

That is, `git checkout -b D A`.  To draw this in, we need to know which of the two graphs to start with again.  It won't matter for a while though, so for now, I'll pick the one with the fast-forward merge:

```
            C4   <-- A, C, D (HEAD)
           /
...--C1--C2
           \
            C3   <-- B
```

> and changes the file to [just the one line `A` again]

```
$ git checkout -b D A
Switched to a new branch 'D'
$ echo A > file
$ git add file
$ git commit -m c7
[D 5724954] c7
 1 file changed, 3 deletions(-)
```

I called this one `C7` to leave some room, skipping a few commit IDs because we're about to stop drawing it in for a while; but now we have:

```
              C7   <-- D (HEAD)
             /
            C4   <-- A, C
           /
...--C1--C2
           \
            C3   <-- B
```

> at 5, the original person to create a branch merges B into A

This time, fast-forward merge is not possible, regardless of which commit-graph structure is the input.  We get a true merge that's not a trivial merge.

#### Let's explore the actual merge algorithm now

At this point I will rewind my demo repository a bit and redo the fast-forward merge, so as to get back to the first situation:

```
$ git checkout A
Switched to branch 'A'
$ git reset --hard 6626cd2
HEAD is now at 6626cd2 c2
$ git merge C
Updating 6626cd2..7af3a02
Fast-forward
 file | 3 +++
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 5724954 (D) c7
* 7af3a02 (HEAD -> A, C) c4
| * 5915b1d (B) c3
|/  
* 6626cd2 c2
* 80e22c8 (master) initial
```

or in my preferred format:

```
              C7   <-- D
             /
            C4   <-- A (HEAD), C
           /
...--C1--C2
           \
            C3   <-- B
```

We have commit `C4` in the index and work-tree and our `HEAD` is attached to the name `A`.  We now run `git merge B` or `git merge <hash of C3>`—it doesn't really matter which.  Git looks at this graph to find the Lowest Common Ancestor node, which in this case is obviously commit `C2`.

The merge algorithm now, in effect, runs two `git diff` commands:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-C2> <hash-of-C4>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-C2> <hash-of-C3>   # what they changed
```

Assuming "we" (`C2`-vs-`C4`) changed only the one file, the change found here will be: *add three lines, `B` `C` `D`, at the end of the file.*  Similarly, the change found for "their" work is *add two lines, `B` and `C`, at the end of the file.*

Git's job is to combine these two changes.  But they conflict: it's not possible to add just two lines, and at the same time, add three lines.  So Git stops with a merge conflict:

```
$ git checkout A
Already on 'A'
$ git merge B
Auto-merging file
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Your next statement is therefore a problem:

> meaning that on A the file is:
>
> ```
> A
> B
> C
> ```

because as we can see, until we fix the merge conflict, that's not what's in the file:

```
$ cat file
A
<<<<<<< HEAD
B
C
D
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======
B
C
>>>>>>> B
```

(I have `merge.conflictStyle` set to `diff3`, producing the `||||||| merged common ancestors` section here, though in this case it's empty anyway).

It is of course possible for the human doing the merge to *set* the contents the way you suggest, or to use `-X ours` or `-X theirs` to choose one of the two changes to take priority.  But the default is a merge conflict, in which case, it's up to you, the human, to resolve it correctly, for whatever the definition of *correct* is in your case.  Let's choose `A` `B` `C` here:

```
$ git checkout --theirs file
$ cat file
A
B
C
$ git add file
$ git commit -m c5
[A eec968d] c5
```

The graph now looks like this:

```
            C4   <-- C
           /  \
...--C1--C2    C5   <-- A (HEAD)
           \  /
            C3   <-- B
```

and the contents of `file` in commit `C5` are the ones we chose.

#### What if we force a trivial merge?  Why is the trivial merge so trivial?

We can reset our conditions again and go back to before we allowed `A` to fast-forward:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~2
HEAD is now at 6626cd2 c2
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 5724954 (D) c7
* 7af3a02 (C) c4
| * 5915b1d (B) c3
|/  
* 6626cd2 (HEAD -> A) c2
* 80e22c8 (master) initial
```

Redrawing this graph my way, we are back to:

```
              C7   <-- D
             /
            C4   <-- C
           /
...--C1--C2   <-- A (HEAD)
           \
            C3   <-- B
```

Let's use `git merge --no-ff C` this time, and explore what the usual algorithm does.  We find the two tip commits, `C2` and `C4`, and find their merge base—the least common ancestor, which is `C2`.  Then we do two diffs:

```
git diff --find-renames C2 C2    # what we changed (nothing!)
git diff --find-renames C2 C4    # what they changed
```

We then combine the "nothing" with whatever they changed.  The result of this combining is of course just *their* changes; these are applied to `C2`, and the result is a commit whose contents match those of `C4`:

```
$ git merge --no-ff C -m c5
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 file | 3 +++
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
*   b47cf02 (HEAD -> A) c5
|\  
| | * 5724954 (D) c7
| |/  
| * 7af3a02 (C) c4
|/  
| * 5915b1d (B) c3
|/  
* 6626cd2 c2
* 80e22c8 (master) initial
```

Note that the contents of `C4` and `C5` match:

```
$ git diff 7af3a02 b47cf02
$
```

and the graph is now as predicted (though Git's drawing is hard to read):

```
              C7   <-- D
             /
            C4   <-- C
           /  \
...--C1--C2----C5   <-- A (HEAD)
           \
            C3   <-- B
```

If we now run `git merge B`, we necessarily call for a true merge—there's no way to slide the name `A` "forward" to `C3`—but again get a conflict:

```
$ git merge B
Auto-merging file
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ cat file
$ cat file
A
<<<<<<< HEAD
B
C
D
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======
B
C
>>>>>>> B
```

The merge conflict is identical to the earlier conflict, as the three input contents were also identical.

Let's once again resolve this the way you suggested, using the three-line `--theirs` version (and I'm going to cheat a bit with a shortcut that removes the need to `git add` it):

```
$ git checkout MERGE_HEAD -- file
$ git commit -m c6
[A 2e66e76] c6
$ cat file
A
B
C
```

(The "cheat" is that `git checkout MERGE_HEAD` extracts the file from commit `C3`, to which `B` points, rather than extracting it from index slot 3.  This wipes out the three conflicted index slot entries, replacing them with a resolved slot-zero entry, so that we are ready to commit the result.)

Now we have this graph:

```
              C7   <-- D
             /
            C4   <-- C
           /  \
...--C1--C2----C5--C6   <-- A (HEAD)
           \      /
            \    /
             \  /
              C3   <-- B
```

#### Back to the commands being used

> finally, at 6, branch D gets merged into A ...

To do this, we must have `HEAD` attached to `A`—it already is—and we run `git merge D` or `git merge <hash of C7>`.  Let's predict what will happen, by finding the merge base of commits `C6` and `C7`, following the graph connections backwards to the best ("lowest") common ancestor.  This time, that's commit `C4`.  What's in `file` in `C4` again?  Let's view it, using the fact that the name `C` points to it:

```
$ git show C:file
A
B
C
D
$
```

So Git will compare the contents of `<hash-of-C4>:file` to the contents of `<hash-of-C6>:file`, to see what we changed—we won't bother with rename detection, or other files, as there are no renames to detect, nor changes to other files:

```
$ git diff C:file A:file
diff --git a/file b/file
index 8422d40..b1e6722 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1,4 +1,3 @@
 A
 B
 C
-D
```

So what *we* changed was to remove the final `D`.

Separately, Git will compare the contents of `<hash-of-C4>:file` to the contents of `<hash-of-C7>:file`, to see what they changed, so:

```
$ git diff C:file D:file
$ git diff C:file D:file
diff --git a/file b/file
index 8422d40..f70f10e 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1,4 +1 @@
 A
-B
-C
-D
```

They removed *three* lines.  These changes should conflict.  Let's see if we are right:

```
$ git merge D
Auto-merging file
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ cat file
A
<<<<<<< HEAD
B
C
||||||| merged common ancestors
B
C
D
=======
>>>>>>> D
```

We are indeed correct: the common ancestor (saved in the work-tree because I have `diff3` as my conflict-style setting) has three lines, while the `HEAD` version keeps two of them but their (`D`) version deletes all three.

(We can go through the same exercise with the slightly simpler graph arising from a fast-forward, but the effect winds up being the same: we get a merge conflict on the same set of lines.  The key is to find the merge base and the two tip commits, and compare the base to each branch tip.  In this case the input to the final merge has this graph:

```
              C7   <-- D
             /
            C4   <-- C
           /  \
...--C1--C2    C5   <-- A (HEAD)
           \  /
            C3   <-- B
```

where `C5` has the same manually-built contents as `C6` in the more complex graph, and `C4` and `C7` are identical and the merge base is still `C4`.)

#### Recursive merge

In a comment on [iBug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53039195/1256452), you ask about recursive merges.  These occur when there is more than one Lowest Common Ancestor.  In a simple tree data structure, there is only ever one LCA, but in directed graphs, there may be more than one.  See [Michael A Bender, Martín Farach-Colton, Giridhar Pemmasani, Steven Skiena, and Pavel Sumazin. Lowest common ancestors in trees and directed acyclic graphs. Journal of Algorithms, 57(2):75–94, 2005.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196677405000854) for two formal definitions; but in general, these occur in graph-directed version control systems (such as Git and Mercurial)
when you make "criss-cross" merges.  For instance, suppose we start with this graph:

```
          o--A   <-- branch1
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--B   <-- branch2
```

We now `git checkout branch1 && git merge branch2`, and then when that succeeds we have:

```
          o--A---M1   <-- branch1
         /      /
...--o--*      /
         \    /
          o--B   <-- branch2
```

We immediately run `git checkout branch2 && git merge branch1~1` (or equivalent, e.g., `git merge <hash of commit A>`) to produce:

```
          o--A---M1   <-- branch1
         /    \ /
...--o--*      X
         \    / \
          o--B---M2   <-- branch2
```

If we now make some more commits on the two branches, we might have, e.g.:

```
          o--A---M1--C   <-- branch1
         /    \ /
...--o--*      X
         \    / \
          o--B---M2--D   <-- branch2
```

We now ask: which commit(s) is or are the lowest common ancestors of the tips of the two branches, commits `C` and `D`?  Starting from `C` and working backwards, we find commit `B` through `M1`, which is reachable from `D` through `M2`, so it is an LCA.  But we also find commit `A` on the straight path, and it is reachable from `D` through the *other* parent of `M2`.

Using either of their definitions, or the simpler one I like that involves counting hops (but this does not work as well as the induced subgraph method when there are many inputs), we find that commits `A` and `B` are *both* LCAs for commits `C` and `D`.  This is where Git's `-s resolve` and `-s recursive` strategies differ.

Under `-s resolve`, Git simply picks one ancestor at (apparently) random, and uses that as the merge base for the two diffs.  Under `-s recursive`, Git finds *all* the LCAs and uses *all* of them as merge bases.  To do this, Git merges all the LCAs, as if you had run `git merge <lca1> <lca2>`, then—if there are more LCAs—`git merge <resulting commit> <lca3>`, and so on.  Each commit is made even if there are conflicts: Git simply takes the conflicted merge, complete with conflict markers, and makes a commit out of it.

(Merging any one pair of LCAs may itself require merging multiple LCAs.  If so, Git merges those recursively: hence the name.)

The final commit, which is temporary as it has no name to retain it, is used as the merge base to which the branch tips are compared.  When the *inner* merges have conflicts, this produces remarkably confusing results and/or merge conflicts.  For the most part, though, it works fairly well.  It gives results that are similar to `-s resolve` for most cases, and for the few cases where the results are different, they *tend* to be better.